# Why is a single function sufficient to specify a canonical transformation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Spivak argues at page 577 in his book Physics for Mathematicians:

[image]

What are the $2n$ relations he is talking about?

Answer (score 1):

In the very next line after OP's quote Spivak is considering the 1-form
$$\vartheta~:=~\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \mathrm{d}q^i - \sum_{i=1}^n P_i \mathrm{d}Q^i~\in~\Gamma(T^{\ast}M) $$ 
in the cotangent bundle of the $2n$-dimensional phase space.
He is effectively referring to the $2n$ component functions of the 1-form $\vartheta$. The fact that $\vartheta$ is closed $\mathrm{d}\vartheta=0$ means that it is locally exact $\vartheta=\mathrm{d}{\cal S}$
and specified by a single generating function ${\cal S}$, cf. the [Poincare Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms).